# How to disable a href when media query detects specific browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I have a responsive grid with 20 images that when touched or clicked open a larger, full-sized corresponding image in a slideshow.

However:

I need to disable that link to the slideshow on mobile only (<=480).

Here is how it works:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="boxInner">
    <a href="slideshow_illustration.html?er_col=0"/><img src="_assets/grid_illustration/geisha.jpg">
    <div class="titleBox">Geisha</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please know: I'm just a photographer/artist struggling to build a responsive personal site, so you will have to talk to me like I'm 10 years old.

Thanks in advance for any time and patience.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, one way to do it without javascript is to use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). This basically disables clicking on the element.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
     .boxInner a {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Isaac! At the risk of looking like a complete moron not once but twice, I will ask the same question as I did Dom up there. Should this work just by resizing my laptop browser, or do I need to test on a phone?

Comment: `pointer-events` is almost fully supported now, although IE < 11.0 is still s.o.l.  ( I think )

Comment: Media Queries can be tested by resizing the browser window. Unfortunately I just realized [pointer-events support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) is a bit mixed. So, depending on what you want to support it might not be ideal. By the way, one easy way to test on iOS is to use the iOS Simulator that comes with xCode. It's free and allows you to emulate an iPhone or iPad on your desktop.

Comment: Thank you Dom and Isaac. I was able to implement the media query solution but not the javascript. Maybe it's a bit over my head but I'll play around with it a little more. Thanks for reminding me about the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery in your site by including this in your page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then write a small script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {
    if (screen.width <= 480) {
        $('.boxInner a').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

This should test if the screen is <= 480, and disable the links if it is.

Comment: Thank you Dom! Now, here's the most embarrassing question EVER! Do I need to test this on a phone (no hosting yet), or should it work when I resize the browser on my laptop?

Comment: It's always best to test on as many devices as possible, but resizing the window is a good start

Comment: I wouldn't use this because:
1. It assumes a fixed page size. If someone on a desktop computer uses a small window and enlarges it, anchors are still unclickable.
2. It creates events for all *currently* existing anchors. If any anchors are creating on the fly or loading later on, it doesn't apply to them. 3. It requires a full external library (jquery) to perform a simple task.